# Maintain visibility of focused UITextView in a UITableView when showing Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, keyboard

I am building a form dynamically that has various types of UI elements for each `UITableViewCell`.

There is one `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UITextView` and I want to be able to maintain visibility when showing the keyboard. I have looked at the other similar questions, but have been unable to find a solution.

I wrote the Swift version of what is recommended by: [Apple's Managing Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

It does not work for two reasons. 
1.) The Keyboard notification is fired before the `TextViewWillBeginEditing`.
2.) The frame of the `UITextView` is in relation to the superview which is the `UITableViewCell`, so the check is wrong.

Here is my current code:

```
func adjustTableViewForKeyboard(notification: NSNotification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

        let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
        let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convertRect(keyboardScreenEndFrame, fromView: view.window)

        if notification.name == UIKeyboardWillHideNotification {
            self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        } else {
            self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height, right: 0)

            rect = self.view.frame;
            rect!.size.height -= keyboardViewEndFrame.height

        }
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.tableView.contentInset

    }


func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
        self.activeTextView = textView;

        if(activeTextView != nil){
            // This check does NOT work due to the TextView's superview is the cell.
            if(!CGRectContainsPoint(rect!, (activeTextView?.frame.origin)!)){
                self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible((activeTextView?.frame)!, animated: true)
            }

        }
    }
```

This works in terms of being able to scroll to all cells, but I also want to make sure the `UITextView` is not hidden by keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use the responder chain to solve this. In your notification handler, try calling `isFirstResponder()` on your text view; if it returns `true`, then you can call the table view-scrolling code from there.

Comment: Could you clarify why `isFirstResponse()` would solve this? In the notification handler the `activeTextView` is `nil` because the keyboard notification is executed prior to the textview's delegate method. Also, this does not address the issue that the tableview scrolling code does not work because the superview of the `UITextView` is the `UITableViewCell` not the `UITableView`

Comment: Your goal is to ensure that the text view remains onscreen, but `textViewDidBeginEditing()` is too late. My idea is that if `isFirstResponder()` returns `true`, then you can perform the animation earlier, in the method that handles the keyboard notification.

Comment: For the frame issues, simply use `convertRect(_:fromView:)` to ensure that you’re converting to/from the right coordinate systems.

Comment: You are THE BOMB. The convertRect function works great, though I tested it in the UITextView delegate (which causes some issues). Maybe I am being dense, but I still don't know how `isFirstResponder()` would help? I do not have access to the `UITextView` unless I get it from `textViewDidBeginEditing()`

Comment: I figured out that I was registered to the wrong notification, `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` instead of `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`. Though I would still like to know how using `isFirstResponder()` would work.

Comment: Ah, yes. You would have to store a reference to the text view, then query it inside that method. Something like `if self.formTextView.isFirstResponder() { }`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a (albeit static cell) form I was building, I was able to use the scrollToRowAtIndexPath method to update the tableview's row positioning to keep my text view on screen.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView == notesTextView {
        tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 3), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

It does require knowledge of the index path section/row and the text view reference in case of multiples, but might be of use?

scrollRectToVisible should also work, but sounds like you have to convert the textview's frame to coordinate system of the scrollview using convertRect:toView or similar first.

Hope this helps - Cheers.